# GDB: examine as instruction with opcodes

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to examine memory as instruction (`x/i`) the way I can see both asm and raw instructions in hex (like with `disassemble /r`)?
Sometimes I want to disassemble some part of memory which GDB refuses to disassemble saying: *"No function contains specified address"*.
The only option is then `x/i`, but I would like to see exactly what hex values are translated to what instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to disassemble some part of memory which GDB refuses to disassemble saying: "No function contains specified address".

The `disas/r 0x1234,0x1235` will work even when GDB can not determine function boundaries. Example:

```
(gdb) disas/r 0x0000000000400803
No function contains specified address.

(gdb) disas/r 0x0000000000400803,0x000000000040080f
Dump of assembler code from 0x400803 to 0x40080f:
   0x0000000000400803:  e8 b8 fd ff ff  callq  0x4005c0 <system@plt>
   0x0000000000400808:  48 81 45 f0 00 10 00 00 addq   $0x1000,-0x10(%rbp)
End of assembler dump.
```